# Lightning Component - force:inputField not rendering

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I am using force:inputField in lightning component but it is not being rendered in the component. I am using compound form.
If I replace force:inputField with ui:InputText or any other ui namespace component it shows up fine.

Below is the markup -

```
<aura:component controller="MyServerController" implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId">

    <ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS0214/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" />
    <!-- init event -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="newCustom" type="CustomObj__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'CustomObj__c' }" />
<form>
    <fieldset class="slds-form--compound">

        <div class="slds-form-element__group">
<div class="slds-form-element__row">    
                <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-2">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" >Custom field 1</label>
                    <force:inputField aura:id="field1"  value="{!v.newCustom.field1__c}"  required="true"/>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-2">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" >Custom field 2</label>
                    <force:inputField aura:id="notes"  value="{!v.newCustom.field2__c}"  required="true"/>

                </div>
            </div>


</div>

    </fieldset>     
    </form>

</aura:component>
```

Anything I am missing ?

Comment: Field names are case sensitive. Did you check to make sure the API name matches exactly?

Comment: @sfdcfox , yes API names matches exactly and my custom obj is not null and fields are being initialized to non null values.

Comment: @sfdcfox if I add ui:inputText on the next row in the form, it shows the input text box with value prepopulated correctly. Only the force:inputfield is not showing up

Comment: I think that it is a bug. Force: inputField only renders when it is placed directly under a component tag. Can you try that..

Comment: @sfdcfox  This is occuring for me when i used the component appera when Custom button in detail view of rec. and Action Type is set to Lightening component.

Comment: @sfdcfox This is occuring for me in same flow, I also added action type lightning component for Lightning action, And also i have used my component in side a page there also i'm facing this problem, can i add this as an issue