# What is the most efficient way to get object field labels in Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, label

I need to display custom object field inputs on Lightning component. This has to support localization.

My code looks like this:

```
<aura:attribute name="myFieldsMap" type="Map" default="{ 'Field1__c': 'Field 1 label', 'Field2__c': 'Field 2 label',  }" />
<aura:attribute name="myObject" type="myObject__c" />

<lightning:input label="{!v.myFieldsMap.Field1__c}" value="v.myObject.Field1__c" />
<lightning:input label="{!v.myFieldsMap.Field2__c}" value="v.myObject.Field2__c" />
```

I get labels in apex using `DescribeFieldResult` and return values to component.

`force:inputField` is not rendered for some reason and I don't want to investigate why ([Lightning Component - force:inputField not rendering](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/152650/lightning-component-forceinputfield-not-rendering))

What I don't like in this solution is that I have to specify `default` value for map with all fields I am using, because if label value is empty, component throws an error. For adding new fields I just want to populate `lightning:input`. Unfortunately I also have to add field definition to list in Apex to get the label, but specifying `default` makes this messy. Is there more elegant way than this?

Answer (score 2):

Best practice and solution would be to get the actual sObject from the server side and put it as the attribute, lets say this is a custom object called TestObj__c:

```
<aura:attribute name="myObject" type="TestObj__c" />
```

Then - all fields that you will attach to components would have labels - also the translated ones!!!

And also - since getting field labels from client side is not supported yet - you can support my idea that does exactly what you have asked for:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cNLeQAM